# query to generate data from a comparison of 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database

I want to ask a fast database query,
there I need a fast query(because is large data's) to display data from table A and table B, and i need to save query into VIEW DB

What is displayed in the new table is all data in table B and data in table A that are not in table B.

The new table will only show data from '% Y-01-01' until today..

sample table :
**table A**

| ID | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 123451 | 2021-01-01 06:21:16 |
| 123452 | 2021-01-01 06:25:44 |
| 123453 | 2021-01-01 06:28:19 |
| 123454 | 2021-01-01 06:28:30 |

**table B**

| ID | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 123451 | 2021-01-01 06:21:16 |
| 123453 | 2021-01-01 06:28:19 |
| 123454 | 2021-01-01 06:28:30 |

**table results :**

| ID | Enroll |
| --- | --- |
| 123451 | 2021-01-01 06:21:16 |
| 123452 | 2021-01-01 06:25:44 |
| 123453 | 2021-01-01 06:28:19 |
| 123454 | 2021-01-01 06:28:30 |

and this is my query :

```
    SELECT
q1.ID, q1.Enroll, emp0003.Shift_ID

FROM(
SELECT
    tableB.ID,
    tableB.Enroll
FROM
    tableB UNION DISTINCT SELECT tableA.ID, tableA.Enroll FROM tableA
) as q1
    INNER JOIN emp0003 ON  emp0003.ID = q1.ID
    WHERE
    Emp0003.IsActive = 'T'
```

run long time and can't save to VIEW DB

Comment: *What is displayed in the new table is all data in table B and data in table A that are not in table B.* I.e. all rows present in at least one table. Trivial `SELECT * FROM table1 UNION DISTINCT SELECT * FROM table2` do this.

Comment: @Akina, this is usefull, but i need the query to save into VIEW DB

Comment: *i need the query to save into VIEW DB* Absolutely unclear phrase...

Comment: i need to join this with other table

Comment: No problems. `.. FROM (SELECT .. UNION SELECT ..) AS total JOIN othertable ..`

Comment: @Akina i was update my real query i used.

Comment: Improve it with `SELECT * FROM A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM b WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE a.id=b.id)`

Comment: i save this query and i have error : 1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: No such restriction. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f6824927f52429663270afcf72e4079 You did something wrongly. Maybe your MySQL is too ancient? upgrade it.

Comment: How about:

`SELECT * FROM A JOIN emp0003 ON emp0003.ID = A.ID AND Emp0003.IsActive = 'T' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM B JOIN emp0003 ON  emp0003.ID = B.ID AND Emp0003.IsActive = 'T'`

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL cannot access underlying indexes, rendering their usefulness questionable.